# What exception should I throw in user defined literals?

Tags: c++

I have a user-defined literal in C++. I would like to save the value in `uint32_t`, but C++ allows literals only for types `unsigned long long int` or `long double`.

My question is what exception should I throw, when the user uses an out of range variable?

The obvious answer would be `std::out_of_range`, but I think, that it's more `std::logic_error` over `std::overflow_error` (as it is something, I can detect even by going through the code).
Because of this I would consider `std::out_of_range` or `std::invalid_argument`.

I was also looking at implementation of `std::chrono`, but I didn't manage to get any information from that.

```
#include <stdexcept>

struct freqHz
{
    uint32_t value;
    constexpr explicit freqHz(uint32_t freq) : value(freq) {}
};

constexpr inline freqHz operator""_Hz(unsigned long long freq)
{
    if (freq >= (1ULL << 32)) {
        throw std::logic_error("Frequency Hz will overflow");
    }
    return freqHz(freq);
}
```

Comment: Well, what exception do you want to make users of your code catch? Also, do you want your code to not be `constexpr`-capable? Because that's how you make your code not be `constexpr`-capable.

Comment: @NicolBolas, The `constexpr` part will at least [be fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/noP_Hf).

Comment: @chris: Is that a C++20 thing or does that work in previous versions?

Comment: @NicolBolas, It should work back to 11, only erroring if the `throw` path is hit. 20 will also let surrounding code containing try-catch be `constexpr` with the same behaviour of a compiler error if a `throw` is executed during compile-time evaluation.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are not allowed to have a try block in a `constexpr` function.  It is legal to have a `throw` expression as long as there exists a value that doesn't throw.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `constexpr` part. I tried using `static_assert`, but that didn't work (obviously) - but it would be nice... this is at least something, except I use it mostly like `function(50_Hz)`, so there is no room for `constexpr`.

Comment: @OndřejSvoboda You can have a throw expression inside the body of a constexpr function, the function call can still be a part of a constant expression as long as the throw expression is not evaluated. Your code is fine. Just add constexpr to the constructor of freqHz and to the user defined literal operator.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, right.  I keep missing that.

Comment: I don't think the choice of exception matters much as in order to call it your clients would have to use this syntax: `operator""_Hz(x)`.  That's the only way to get a run-time value in.  Otherwise the input is a literal and the code will not compile if not in range.

Comment: @HowardHinnant one could write func(5000000000_Hz) and that would compile just fine, except it will compile to raise an exception (it's smaller than 2^64, but bigger than 2^32)

Comment: @OndřejSvoboda:  You're right, my bad.  What I said is true only if assign the result to a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: If we get `constexpr!`, I think that will do the trick (detect overflow at compile-time).